# Extracting a substring after a match position using grok in logstash

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Objective : I have a log file from where I want to extract the amount details after the string **Amount:::** in the below given log file.

What I have Done so far: Since it is a Custom Parsing, I have created a custom pattern using RegEx and I am trying to Implement it using logstash.

here is my log file -

```
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 3000.00  
28-04-2017 12:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 31000.00  
28-04-2017 14:15:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 10000.00  
28-04-2017 11:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 9000.00  
28-04-2017 08:15:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 7000.00
```

I have used Regex to find the string **Amount:::**
Note : I want to extract the sub string which is coming after the string **Amount:::**

here are my Custom Patterns I have used in Grok:
(but it doesn't yield good results)

```
CUSTOM_AMOUNT (?<= - Amount::: ).*    
CUSTOM_AMOUNT (?<=Amount::: )%{BASE16FLOAT}
```

here is my `logstacsh.conf`-

```
input { 
    file {
       path => "D:\elk\data\amnt_parse.txt"
       type => "customgrok"
       start_position => "beginning"
       sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
         } 
      }  
 filter{ 
       if[type]== "customgrok" {

            if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] { 
                              grok { 
                                   patterns_dir => "D:\elk\logstash-5.2.1\vendor\bundle\jruby\1.9\gems\logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2\patterns\custom" 

                                    match => { "message" => "%{CUSTOM_AMOUNT:amount" } 
                                    add_field => { "subType" => "Amount"           } 

    } 

    }
    }  
 mutate {
      gsub => ['message', "\t", " "] 
        }  } }

 output {
     stdout {
         codec => "rubydebug"
            }
     elasticsearch {
         index => "amnt_parsing_change"
          hosts =>"localhost"

            }
            }
```

Our intension is to Visualize and to perform aggregation operations based on the extracted substring using Kibana and Elasticsearch.
but it stores the log file into the variable `"message"`. as you can see here, `match => { "message" => "%{CUSTOM_AMOUNT:amount" }`.

here is how the line is stored inside `"message"`, when I tried to view it in **Kibana** -

```
"message": "28-04-2017 11:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 9000.00\r",  
"message": "28-04-2017 12:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 31000.00\r",    
"message": "28-04-2017 11:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 9000.00\r",
```

Logstash file is loading the Data(log file) and Index is also getting created but `Custom Pattern` isn't giving expected result. 
what are possibilities to extract the sub string which I have mentioned above ? or do we have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do :

```
filter {
     grok {
                match => {
                        "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:Date} %{WORD:LogSeverity}\s+%{WORD:LogInfo} \(%{NOTSPACE:JavaClass}\) \- Amount::: %{NUMBER:Amount}"
                        }
        }
                mutate
                        {
                                gsub =>
                                [
                                        "Data"," ","-"
                                ]
                                #If you dont want those fields
                                remove_field => ["Date","LogSeverity","LogInfo","JavaClass"]

                        }
        }
```

I recommend you to read the documentations :

[Grok Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)
[Grok Patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns)

You can use the following debugger :

[GrokDebbuger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. now, what if my log file is multilined? like, `28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  upiinfo (UPI_CustAccReg_ServiceImpl.java278) - accntDetailscom.fss.connect.domain.upi.UpiCustAccReg@5007c95d
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  upiinfo (UPI_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 3000.00
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  upiinfo (UPI_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java308) - Formatted Amount::: 000000300000
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO ` what would be the solution then?

Comment: '28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO upiinfo (UPI_CustAccReg_ServiceImpl.java278) - accntDetailscom.fss.connect.domain.upi.UpiCustAccReg@5007c95‌​d 
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO upiinfo (UPI_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 3000.00 
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO upiinfo (UPI_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java308) - Formatted Amount::: 000000300000 
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO ' 

Your log is formatted like this ? 

could you copy and past with exactly format. INCLUDING new lines.

Comment: here you go.. a sample log from the log file.. `28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java335) - Split_amount::::
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 3000.00
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java308) - Formatted Amount::: 000000300000 28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java327) - Transaction Status :::: 
  abcinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java335) - Split_amount::::
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (ABC_TxnLog_ServiceImpl.java295) - Amount::: 3000.00`

Comment: OK.! 
But what I want is a sample with exactly format, because like this I don't know where each of the log line start and where it ends.

Each time stamp correspond to a new line?

Comment: YEAH!! @rabbit each timestamp corresponds to new line. `28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (g_) - Amount::: 3000.00
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (_) - Formatted Amount::: 000000300000
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (ABCog_) - TXNLOG status :::: Y
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (ABC_Log) - TXNID TxnLog Update :::: 
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (Aog_) - Transaction Status :::: 
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (ALog_) - Split_amount::::
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (ABC_) - Amount::: 3000.00
28-04-2017 14:45:50 INFO  ABCinfo (ABC_) - Formatted Amount::: 000000300000`